# How to update worksheet range if address contains special characters?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to update range using `/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='<address>')` request from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. In my case document contains two sheets with names 'invoice' and 'invoice-lines'. Cell's to update address is 'invoice-lines'!$B$5 in second sheet. Address I get from API using GET `/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/names` request.

My request with address example:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet-id}/range(address=''invoice-lines'!$B$5')`

I expect result the same as I get when updating range in sheet 'invoice' with request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet-id}/range(address='invoice!$B$5')`,
but actual result is 400 Error with message `"Syntax error at position 18 in 'address=''invoice-lines'!$B$5''."`

I tried encode URL and remove quotes. Without quotes in address I get error `The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.`

How my request should look like to update this range?